# Error Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?' with Array in userInfo of a NSTimer

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, nstimer, skspritenode

Hello that is my code :

[image]

I don't understand why I have this error… Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put an array of `SKSpriteNode` into `userInfo` of the timer.
When the timer fires the called method returns `userInfo` as `AnyObject`.
Just downcast the object to the proper type.

```
let listAlienBullet = timer.userInfo as! [SKSpriteNode] 
let alienForDestroying = listAlienBullet[0]
let bulletForDestroying = listAlienBullet[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`userInfo` is `AnyObject`. You can't subscript `AnyObject`.

Cast `listAlienBullet` to an `Array` of SKSpriteNodes.

```
if let listAlienBullet = timer.userInfo as? [SKSpriteNode] {
    let alienForDestroying = listAlienBullet[0]
    let bulletForDestroying = listAlienBullet[1]
}
```

Comment: When I try this I have another error :                        Type 'Dictionary<Key, Value>?' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Comment: sorry old habits. change Dictionary to [String:AnyObject] same thing, but you have to tell the compiler what the dictionary should have in it. Type safety and all that.